# Determining whether the Polynomial is a vector space.

Tags: vector-spaces

Im trying to understand the way to deal with this polynomial in order to decide if it is a vector space or not.

$$\{ ax^2 + |a|x^2 + bx - b \}\qquad  a,b \in\mathbb R$$

Comment: The question is not whether a polynomial is a vector space (it is _not_) but whether a _set_ of polynomials is a vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The polynomial $x^2$ (arising from $a=\frac{1}2$) has no additive inverse (since $-x^2$ cannot be obtained by any choice of $a$) and hence the space is not a vector space.

Comment: what if a=-1 ? now you can get -$x^2$

Comment: $ax^2 + |a|x^2=0$ when $a$ is negative.